# Telerik report in ASPX which accepts an array

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webmethod, telerik-reporting

I have an MVC3 application and we are using Telerik Reporting.  The Telerik report viewer must be hosted in an ASPX page named ReportPage.aspx. In its PageLoad method is logic to determine which report to display based on the querystring. I want to originate a request for a report from an MVC view and I would like the view to remain present, so I either need a popup or a new browser window for the display of the report.  Once the user closes the report window, the original window should display intact.

I believe I can meet the above requirements, but here is the complication.  I need to pass an large array of integers to ReportPage.aspx as an argument, so querystring won't work for me.  As far as I know, I need to use a JSON object and a WebMethod to pass the array.  But I don't see how the WebMethod (even if it is a method of ReportPage.aspx) can open ReportPage.aspx.

Does anyone see a way to make this work?

Comment: You have a large number of parameters -> so use HTTP POST instead of GET. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If your asp.net web site and your MVC web site have access to a shared database then:

1. Store dynamically the large array in the shared database and assign a unique report ID
2. Pass in the query string the report ID only.
3. In the aspx page load the report using the report ID
4. Run a sql job every night that deletes the previous day report IDs. No need to store them forever